# Extra arguments in call for self defined function?

Tags: ios, swift

Inside `API` class I have a singleton object with a method called `submitAnswer` (see blow),

```
func submitAnswer(id: Int, quality: Int) {
    Alamofire.request(
        "\(API_ENDPOINT)/cards?next=true",
        method: .post,
        parameters: answerParams(id: id, quality: quality),
        headers: requestHeaders()
        ).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let JSON):
                let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
                print(response)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }
}
```

When I try to call this method inside the controller, I got an extra argument 'quality' in call error.

```
@IBAction func correctBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let card_id = card!["data"]["id"].intValue
    API.sharedInstance.submitAnswer(id: card_id, quality: 0) {
        API.sharedInstance.nextCard() { card in
            self.card = card
            self.updateContent()
        }
    }
}
```

`quality` parameter is obviously inside the method definition. Why am I having this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why am I having this error

It's because of the curly brace at the end of the line:

```
API.sharedInstance.submitAnswer(id: card_id, quality: 0) {
```

The implication of that syntax is that the curly brace introduces a trailing closure, which would require that you have declared `submitAnswer` to accept a *third* parameter that is some sort of function. But you have not.